# RECO beacons and server connection

Tags: bluetooth, server, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon, beacon

I have a product called RECO Manager Plus. Basically it is a device connect to the router that scans beacons (by bluetooth) and can send requested data through network.

There is a function in this devices that sends constantly info to a specific place,
as it follows:

```
http://<server address>[:<port>]/[<path>]
```

I want to obtain these data in my computer that is connected to the router as well.

My PC IP is 192.168.0.2.

Port I was thinking about anyone, so `666` might work.

I didn't understand what does path means.... and the manual is not really well written.

After all that, I was planning to use netstat command to listen the port.

Or if path means a place in my computer to be saved I would open saved file to check data.

Does anyone have some idea how to proceed?

How should I write the above command to work properly?

Thanks very much

**Additional info:** [manual](https://s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/perples-member-center/utils/RECOManagerPlus_Reporting_Guide_v0.5_en.pdf%22reference%20manual%22)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The configuration appears to be for what is commonly called a "webhook", meaning it is designed to send data to a web server.  The **path** part of the setting refers the part of the URL that comes after the hostname and port.  For the page you are looking at right now, the URL is: 
 `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43981467/reco-beacons-and-server-connection` and the path part is `/questions/43981467/reco-beacons-and-server-connection`

The path really only matters if you are sending the data to a web server, because web servers are often configured with special software to process data sent to a specific path.

If you are using `netstat`, the path doesn't matter, but whatever you put in that configuration setting will be included in the data sent over the socket in a standard HTTP format.  To understand how this works, look at this page that describes how a HTTP POST looks at the socket level:

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp

`POST /test/demo_form.php HTTP/1.1
Host: w3schools.com
name1=value1&name2=value2`

The block above shows the characters sent over the socket for a HTTP POST operation to `http://w3schools.com//test/demo_form.php`.  You'll see that the path part of the URL appears in the first line, the host in the second line, and the data comes after that.  Something similar will be sent to `netstat` if when you configure the RECO Manager Plus as you describe.

Comment: Thanks very much for the explanation. Could you please check the https://www.w3schools.com/test/demo_form.php link for me please? I think it's not working anymore... is it only here or for you doesn't work as well? Best regards!

Comment: No that URL should not work -- it is just an example used to describe how a HTTP POST operation works with a socket.  I have removed the hyperlink formatting so it is not misleading.